# How to validate deeply nested data structures using Pydantic?

Tags: python, pydantic

Suppose I have the following data structure:

```py
{
  "code": 123,
  "a": {
    "b": {
      "c": {
        "d": {
          "value": "hello world"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I want to validate its structure using Pydantic, and access the `code` and `value` fields. For this example, the interesting data is only at the root level, and at the innermost nesting level.

To handle the nesting I could create a few helper model classes:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

sample = {"code": 123, "a": {"b": {"c": {"d": {"value": "hello world"}}}}}


class D(BaseModel):
    value: str


class C(BaseModel):
    d: D


class B(BaseModel):
    c: C


class A(BaseModel):
    b: B


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    code: int
    a: A


obj = MyModel(**sample)
print(obj.code, obj.a.b.c.d.value)
```

Is there a way to "shortcut" the "a" - "d" nesting levels somehow, so I wouldn't need as many helper classes?

Comment: write some code that generates these classes for you based on some syntax that you come up with that describes the inheritance tree

Comment: That's an idea, but, for 4 nesting levels, wouldn't that be an overkill? I'm wondering if there's a simple way to do this, that I have missed.

Comment: if it is just 4 levels why bother wanting a different way of writing these classes, it is a case nobody else needs so the PyDantic team will not add a feature to the library

Comment: if `d` is always a sub class of `a-b-c` why not only write `d`

Comment: @rioV8 regarding "why not only write `d`", could you share a complete example?

Answer (score 0):

Use [**Self-Referenced models**](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/postponed_annotations/#self-referencing-or-recursive-models):

```py
from typing import Union

from pydantic import BaseModel


class GenericData(BaseModel):
    data: Union[str, 'GenericData']


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    code: int
    data: GenericData


if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = MyModel(
        code=123,
        data=GenericData(
            data=GenericData(
                data=GenericData(
                    data=GenericData(
                        data=GenericData(
                            data='hello world'
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
    print(obj.code, obj.data.data.data.data.data)
```

---

With good old [**Data Classes with "Self" type**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Self):

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Union, Self


@dataclass
class GenericData:
    data: Union[str, Self]


@dataclass
class MyModel:
    code: int
    data: GenericData


if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = MyModel(
        code=123,
        data=GenericData(
            data=GenericData(
                data=GenericData(
                    data=GenericData(
                        data=GenericData(
                            data='hello world'
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
    print(obj.code, obj.data.data.data.data.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [an example in Pydantic's Github issues using AliasPath](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/7251). Adapting it for my original example, I get:

```
from pydantic import AliasPath, BaseModel, Field

sample = {"code": 123, "a": {"b": {"c": {"d": {"value": "hello world"}}}}}


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    code: int
    value: str = Field(validation_alias=AliasPath("a", "b", "c", "d", "value"))


obj = MyModel(**sample)
print(obj.code, obj.value)
```